# IIS redirecting subdomain and an optional path

Tags: regex, iis

How can I redirect a subdomain to a path BUT the path may also contain the subdomain. It's not any subdomain so I don't need wildcards but a specific one so for example using 'test' as the subdomain:

```
test.example.com/test/this-is-a-test
```

or

```
test.example.com/this-is-a-test
```

which I'd like either one to redirect to:

```
example.com/test/this-is-a-test
```

This is what I have so far but I cannot get it to work:

```
<rule name="redirect test.example.com" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^test.example.com(/test)?" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://www.example.com/test/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Comment: `HTTP_HOST` can only contain the domain name part, and never contain `/test`. So, your rule simply never works the way you wanted. Please modify `match` tag instead if you want to work on paths like `/test`. Besides, create multiple rules so that you don't need to force yourself to write complicated regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was able to implement a rule that fit my needs and I have added it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should've been rather simple but due to my unfamiliarity with the IIS rewrite module it became complicated. I misunderstood one important thing which is `match url=...` is not actually the full URL but rather the path after domain.com/

So after that revelation it was easy to implement like so:

```
<match url="^(test)?/?(.*)" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^test.example.com" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="https://www.example.com/test/{R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
```